# SharePoint view - how to see items assigned to me or to a group I'm in?

Tags: sharepoint

At work we have a view in SharePoint for IT service requests.  I can see all the SRs assigned to me

```
Assigned Technician
is equal to
[Me]
```

and I can add conditions to see SRs for any group I specify:

```
Assigned Technician
is equal to
ourdomain\somegroup
```

What I *can't* figure out how to do, though, is create a view that will show me SRs for me, and for *all the groups I'm in*.  I can add groups one-by-one individually, but I haven't found a filter (something like [My Groups]) that would give me SRs for all my groups.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if there is an equivalent way of doing this in the UI, but here is how it would be done using the [Membership Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544234.aspx) in CAML:

```
<Or>
  <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
  </Membership>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
    <Value Type="Integer">
      <UserID/>
    </Value>
  </Eq>
</Or>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: For people that don't know how to use this (like me): open your view in sharepoint designer, switch to code view and add this code to <where> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, you can create a second list that maps users to groups, use Me filter on that list and use connection to filter the SR list using this list, you will still need to click on each group name to change the filter to that list